# How to convert objc NSDictionary to Swift

Tags: swift

How to fix this error:

```
func loginMobilephone(phone : String , password : String , withBlock block : ((result:NSDictionary , error: NSError)-> Void)!)
{
    var params : AnyObject! = ["username" :phone,"passwd": password, "session_id" : Constant.instance().session]

    var path : String! = "/account/common/login";
    NetworkManager.sharedClient().postPath(path, parameters: params, withBlock: block)
    NetworkManager.sharedClient().postPath(<#path: String!#>, parameters: <#[NSObject : AnyObject]!#>, withBlock: <#(([NSObject : AnyObject]!, NSError!) -> Void)!##([NSObject : AnyObject]!, NSError!) -> Void#>)
}
```

error is:

> Cannot invoke 'postPath' with an argument list of type '(String!,
>   parameters: AnyObject!, withBlock: ((result: NSDictionary, error:
>   NSError) -> Void)!)'

or how to convert this to Swift:

```
+(void)loginMobilephone:(NSString *)phone password:(NSString *)password withBlock:(void (^)(NSDictionary *, NSError *))block{
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"username" : phone,
                             @"passwd" : password,
                             @"session_id":[[Constant instance] session]
                             };
    [[NetworkManager sharedClient] postPath:APIUSERLOGIN parameters:params withBlock:block]; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

params should be a dictionary [NSObject : AnyObject] instead of AnyObject!.

Try like this:

```
let params: [NSObject : AnyObject] = ["username" : phone, "passwd" : password, "session_id" : Constant.instance().session]
```

and change you method parameters to this

```
func loginMobilephone(phone: String, password: String, withBlock block: ((result: [NSObject : AnyObject] , error: NSError)-> Void) ) {
    // ... code
}
```